# Can I use Python to time an external C++ .exe and grab its return value too?

Tags: c++, python, time

Is there a way I can, from within a Python program, run a C++ .exe and time how long it takes to return a value (and also be able to print to screen what that program's return value is)? These programs are C++ console programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
import subprocess
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
h = subprocess.Popen(...) # See subprocess module documentation for the args
h.communicate()
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Return Code: %d" % h.returncode)
print("Delta: %s" % (t2 - t1))
```

Should work.

([Subprocess module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html))

Comment: @Hurkyl -- good catch, I threw `wait()` in there but `communicate()` is better.

Comment: It isn't working unfortunately; "Access Denied". Inside Popen I have the path to the .exe

Comment: Do you have it in a list: `subprocess.Popen([path])`?  Also, does the user running the python script have access to run the exe?

Comment: Ah I figured it out it needs h = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\test.exe"])

Comment: Yeah, so the r signifies its a  "raw string" -- without it the backslashes are interpreted as escape characters.  Nice work.

Comment: Does it make sense that a simple C++ program that does nothing but return the number 1234 takes over 40 milliseconds?

Comment: Most of it will likely be due to the overhead required to start the subprocess.  For example, if the program `printf()`'d some string and that took ~40msecs, printing the same string one hundred times would take significantly less than 4 seconds.

Comment: 40msecs does seem a bit long, maybe its a Windows thing.  On my linux laptop it takes around 3msecs.